# Error when localize ios app to support multiple languge

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have two questions

1. Have any tutorial for localizing iOS app to support multiple language with **app not using storyboard**?
2. I doing my app without storyboard, I localized it by created Base.lproj folder in my project direction, copy .xib to it, and added language in Project->Info->Localization.(I tested successfully on demo) but with my app when I build and run on simulator my app doesn't update according to setting language on simulator, it only update when I rebuild. Anyone could give me a reason or doubtful questions?

Comment: Very strange!! The problem only happens when i test on simulator, but on Device my project run exactly. If it's a bug of Xcode?

Comment: It happens sometimes. Delete your app from the Simulator, Clean your project in Xcode (in Product -> Clean), and do this for *all* projects and librairies if you have more than one. After that, rebuild everything and deploy again to the Simulator.

Answer (score 3):

When you localize resources in your Xcode project, you don't need to *copy* anything: Xcode does everything for you. If you start copying things here and there, you might get lost, and files might not even get copied to your app bundle.

What you need to do is:

1/ Reference all languages in your Xcode project

[image: Project localization]

2/ Create a new "Strings" file in your project using Xcode, call it "Localizable.strings", and create localized versions of it *through Xcode*, using the "Localization" pane in the File inspector

[image: File localization]

3/ Once you have created multiple versions of your Strings file, enter a sample string that you will test in your app, like:

```
"HELLO_STR" = "Hello, world";
```

in your English version, and

```
"HELLO_STR" = "Bonjour tout le monde";
```

in your French version.
Then in your application startup code, add this line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO_STR", nil));
```

The message logged in your console should now correspond to your device or simulator language setting.

4/ You now need to add all localized strings to your Localizable.strings files.

5/ As for the XIBs, it works exactly like the Storyboards: you can ask Xcode to create a localizable version of all your XIBs. They are copied and bundled by Xcode in much the same way as the strings file we already built in steps 1-4. It is better to do that once you have "finished" designing your interfaces, because any subsequent modification to one localized XIB version will have to be repeated in all other localized versions.

Good luck.

Comment: I haven't done my problem, my default project doesn't have en.lproj folder causing i have to create en.lproj folder and copy localizable file into it. And i don't use storyboard. I waste  hours for this problem, There is any sugestion for me? Thanks you.